# PHP Script on a template page & dealing with URI's

Tags: theme-development

I am working building a page within a template which will be a PHP script to do various URL-based things (basically an API).

Creating a page is simple enough, I created `page-mypage.php` in the template folder, and created a page in the Wordpres front-end with the slug `mypage`.

This all works, but I am running into this issue

http://example.com/mypage <-- Works, loads the content of `page-mypage.php`

http://example.com/mypage/stuff/ <-- 404 Error

Is there a way to capture all the URI after "/mypage" without generating a 404 error?

Comment: What kind of "URL-based things" are you trying to do? What type of output are you expecting?

Comment: It's essentially a wrapper to a 3rd party REST api

Comment: What type of output are you generating?